# I can't download anything from Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center

I've installed ubuntu 13.04 a few day's ago and U.S.C. (Ubuntu Software Center) worked perfect. Yesterday I couldn't download any more, the proggress tab show the number 1
and it is **Enabling component of the distribution** with 1 item waiting: **Updating cache**

(I'm Dutch and 12 years old so I don't know much about computers)

Answer (score 1):

When you install Ubuntu you have to do an update. You have to do this because in time of installing the system you have the OS as it was on release date. So updating improves your OS and protect your system with bug fixes etc.

Because we don't have much information about your current situation please open a terminal and type in

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and after that

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now you have the latest packages and can start working.

Comment: it don't work, it says: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: Did you do that after a reboot? And with superuser rights?

Comment: superures rights? is that something like administrator, yes

Comment: Yes, you're absolutley right. For that use [sudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo). Maybe there is another progress running that blocks the update or update the OS itself.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple. Just run a few commands...

You can copy these commands and paste them into a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

The first command deletes one lock file and second deletes the other one in the cache directory.

Now run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your system is busy installing updates. That's why you get an error using apt-get. Just let everything finish updating and it will work.